# Meteor.js Aysnc is not returning the result keep loading

Tags: node.js, meteor

Here, am calling the method to get the Quickblox result in async method. While i am print the value in console i can get it but the application keep loading not return the result.

Server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  allquickbloxusers_Methods: function(){
    var params = {login: ["99999"]};

    var asyncCall = QB1.users.get(params, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, QBuser) {
        if(QBuser) {
            return QBuser;  
            } else {
                return err;
            }       
        }));

    var syncCall = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncCall);
    var res = syncCall();

    // now you can return the result to client.
    return res;  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `Meteor.wrapAsync` you want to pass it the actual function, not the result of a called function. Like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
  allquickbloxusers_Methods: function(){
    var params = {login: ["99999"]};

    var syncCall = Meteor.wrapAsync(QB1.users.get)

    var res = syncCall(params);

    // now you can return the result to client.
    return res;  
  }
});
```

Basically `wrapAsync` gives you back a new function that you call with the parameters of the original function.

Knowing this, you can make the function even more concise:

```
Meteor.methods({
  allquickbloxusers_Methods: function(){
    var params = {login: ["99999"]};

    return Meteor.wrapAsync(QB1.users.get)(params)
  }
});
```